# How to secure passwords and prevent login spoofing?

Tags: security, encryption

Let's talk about password security. How does one design a system that prevents anyone with database access (such as a database administrator or software engineer) from logging into an account? Specifically, if a project is open-source where the code and encryption methods are public knowledge, how is each layer secured to prevent spoofing. While the passwords may be cryptographically secure, can any not just pull the open-source repo down, modify the authentication method and submit the encrypted value to login as well? Allow  me to design a system in which is commonly recommended where this may be possible.

Plain-text passwords should never be stored in a database, we all know that. Instead, the encrypted password using a **slow one-way encryption** should be stored. Additional steps can be taken, but we'll start simple with this scenario for now. The administrators of the database never know what the plain-text password is. All they know is the encrypted form of the users password. When the user submits their login credentials they can do one of the following options:

- Submit username and plain-text password, the server then encrypts it and checks the database for the username:encrypted_password keypair. This is a poor implementation as the unencrypted password is transmitted across the network and may be stored in various logs.
- Submit username and client-side generated encrypted password, the server then checks the database for the username:encrypted_password keypair. This is better, as the unencrypted password is never transmitted on the network. However, this poses a different issue below **which is the root question this post serves to understand**.

If the database stores the username and encrypted password then what additional layers of security can be done **to prevent someone from modifying the open-source software to submit a users known encrypted password?** Restated; if a malicious database administrator or software engineer snoops into the database, takes someones encrypted password, modifies a fork to always submit that encrypted password (thus never performing the client-side hash) what additional layer of security can be used to prevent this form of attack? The malicious attacker does not know the plain text password, but they are easily able to login to account.

The obvious answers are to:

1. Limit database read access to as few employees as required
2. Salt passwords with a user-unique salt that is stored in a different database, and limit access to this to even fewer people. This salting must occur server-side.
3. Use a common global pepper that is defined outside of the database which the application uses to encrypted everything again. This peppering must occur server-side.
4. Use a different authentication manager, such as LDAP or Active Directory

When utilizing methods 1, 2, and 3 we can develop a fairly strict and tight password security layer. Those who know the global pepper but do not have access to the database will not be able to get the finalized encrypted password, therefore they're unable to perform any operation because they do not have the salt and peppered encrypted password. But what about the database administrators? They have the fully encrypted password, and the salt, all they need is the pepper right? Assuming the pepper was properly deployed, it will likely reside as either an environment variable on the server host or in a configuration file that isn't committed or stored in any form of database (traditional database, git, etc.) Awesome, so we've at least determined one way to **prevent spoofing by limiting database and deployment access to two different individuals or departments therefore requiring collusion to get all required pieces of information to perform the attack.**

**However, how do you employ this level of security and trust when there is only 1 employee?** That single employee is going to be the database administrator, software developer, deployment engineering, etc. **How do we instill trust to the user, and show to the community, that the developer is not able to spoof their login?** A project depending on a service like LDAP or AD requires additional configuration, understanding of how those products work, and many times just isn't necessary for the application you're developing.

Comment: While I think this is a valid question, questions like it (centered more on security *theory* rather than implementation) are better fits for Stack Overflow's sister site, [Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @esqew thanks for pointing that out to me, I'll post it over there

Comment: "*How do we instill trust to the user, and show to the community, that the developer is not able to spoof their login?*" How do users trust *any* software proprietor, big or small, that any of their data is being handled securely? I think the premise of your question (that users actively are seeking *provable* security of their data) is flawed. Can you elaborate a bit more as to what you're specifically asking here?

Comment: I think you got password hashing wrong. Its not supposed to be done by the client side, it is done by the server, for the same reason you stated. See: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8596/https-security-should-password-be-hashed-server-side-or-client-side. And no, you should not be transmitting passwords across the network in clear, you should use [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)

Comment: For open-source projects, a user likely will not trust the server and therefore won't want their plain-text password being transmitted at any point to said server. The server now has (per the link) a user-held mnemonic so your plain-text password isn't exposed in transit or in memory (which is likely to be shared with other sites). The server uses a user-unique salt to make the mnemonic application specific (my sha-256 password on appA is different than appB now) which protects encrypted password leaks and hides account-linking. Global pepper prevents DBA (internal) maliciousness via isolation

Comment: Adding on, if someone finally did get your user-held mnemonic they'd then need to brute-force the unencrypted password to get your plain-text which, when using a good encryption algorithm such as bcrypt or argon2 won't be realistic. Hashing both client and server side provide even greater security.

Comment: "*For open-source projects, a user likely will not trust the server and therefore won't want their plain-text password being transmitted at any point to said server*" Citation needed...

Comment: @esqew I suppose a better way to phrase it would be "why should a user ever trust the server with their plain-text password". Encrypting client side (regardless of knowledge of whether the password is encrypted server-side again) now provides the user with a second layer to protect their plain-text password. While it does **not** aid in the prevention of unwanted authentications to that specific site/app, it shields the plain-text with another layer which helps protect you credentials from being used on other sites as more work is required to find the plain text password.

Comment: Even if you encrypt the data in table, the dba has the private key. Even if you hash the password with salt and transmit over TLS, the network admin probably has access to your SSL private key and can see any plaintext password crossing the network.

Answer (score 0):

> slow one-way encryption

The one-way function is called *hash*

> Submit username and plain-text password .. This is a poor implementation as the unencrypted password is transmitted across the network

Not really. The solution is using the *https* (TLS generally). There is no reason not to use/enforce using https.If you generate anything on the client side, then the generated value becomes the password. There is no reason to reinvent the wheel and make it more complicated than necessary.

> But what about the database administrators?

The DB admin has usually much more power than impersonating a user. If having application-level credentials, the admin could read or modify the data in the database without ever needing to know the user credentials. Malicious admin is a disaster for any company. Most of the serious databases separate the roles (application could access data, admin could manage the db yet not see the data, backup team manages the backups), but it's not easy to separate the roles mainly in small companies, where the same team manages the databases and configure the application deployment.

> prevent someone from modifying the open-source software to submit a users known encrypted password?

The OSS is usually well reviewed, I'm more concerned about custom implementations done wrong. But indeed nothing prevents any service provider to store passwords in plain without the client being aware. So it's up to the clients/users not to reuse their passwords for multiple services.

When it comes to the authentication, I'd consider MFA (multifactor authentication) or using a well know trusted 3rd party IdP as the best practice today. Still it won't protect you against an evil admin or developer.

> How ... show to the community, that the developer is not able to spoof their login?

If it's running on the server, there are no means to provided any ensurance as that. Using a 3rd party well known IdP (there are plenty of free or commercial services)  users could at least trust the developers/admins have no access to the user credentials.